# can't convert Symbol into Integer (TypeError) : while using bunny popping queue using bunny client only on windows

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq

Though I have searched enough but could not get help resolving this issue. I am very new to Ruby so please pardom me if I am missing something very basic.

While executing below code on windows I am getting error "C:/Users/shhashmi/workspace/rabbitmqSender/sender.rb:36:in `[]': can't convert Symbol into Integer (TypeError)
    from C:/Users/shhashmi/workspace/rabbitmqSender/sender.rb:36:in`getItem'
    from C:/Users/shhashmi/workspace/rabbitmqSender/sender.rb:59:in `'"

However code is working fine on CentOS.

```
require "bunny"
require "net/http"

# Rabbit MQ
@host = "test.host"
@queue = "test.queue"

#@host = "localhost"
#@queue = "TEST"


# Put your target machine here
@target = "http://localhost:3000/"

def getItem
b = Bunny.new(:host=>@host, :port=>5672,)
# start a communication session with the amqp server
                b.start

                # declare a queue
                q = b.queue(@queue, :auto_delete=>true)


                # declare default direct exchange which is bound to all queues
                e = b.exchange("")



                # publish a message to the exchange which then gets routed to the queue

                #e.publish("Hello, everybody! 211", :key => @queue)
                #e.publish("Hello, everybody! 311", :key => @queue)

                # get message from the queue
                msg = q.pop[:payload]

                puts "This is the message: " + msg + "\n\n"

                # close the connection
                b.stop
                return msg
end


getItem
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the error with your code. The problem is with this line:

```
msg = q.pop[:payload]
```

The Queue#pop method returns an array of 3 items, after popping the message from the queue. The method should look something like this:

```
delivery_info, message_properties, msg = q.pop
```

Now, you should see your message payload in the 'msg' variable. You could inspect the other two results to glean any useful information (e.g. number of remaining messages in the queue) or ignore them altogether if you don't need them